# preloader with jquery

Tags: jquery, preloader

I am trying to make a preloader with jquery.Can somebody please tell me how early we can get the width and height of an image so I can place the preloader.gif at the middle of the actual image with absolute positioning?

In other word I want to call a function as soon as image width and height are set.How to do it?Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

That should be as soon as the image request is returned to the browser. However, if you know the exact width and height of your image, you should set them with the `height=` and `width=` attributes in HTML, or the `width:` and `height:` properties of CSS. that will ensure the browser knows the sizes exactly even before it has to request the images.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Actually I want that preloader thing to happen to all the images in a single page,so width and height will be different to each other.

Answer (score 0):

---

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2RHY/1)

<sub>**the image kinda got messed up somehow in the example... sorry*</sub>

---

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://th06.deviantart.net/fs71/PRE/f/2010/263/0/d/random_manga_oc_2_by_alcuinus-d2z45x0.png";
img.onload = function(){
    this.style.marginLeft = (-this.width / 2) + "px";
    this.style.marginTop = (-this.height / 2) + "px";
    alert("This image's dimensions are " + this.width + " by " + this.height);
}
```

That will get you there.  The basic concept is make a js image object (if the image is already loaded in the markup it will be loaded from cache), and when it is loaded assign the margin values of the HTML version based on the dimensions of the js loaded version.